# QGIS icon becomes a "blank sheet" in windows taskbar

Tags: qgis, windows-10

Is it just for me that icon for QGIS appears like a "blank sheet" on the Windows taskbar like this:

[image: blank sheet]

... after some time or "heavy work" (haven't 100% understood when it happens).

Currently running: QGIS 3.4.5 on Windows 10 x64, I assume that this is some kind of Windows feature, anyone else that experienced this and solved it?

Comment: I had this exact issue for a while with a previous version of QGIS. It resolved itself when I updated to the next minor version. Try unpinning QGIS from the taskbar re-pinning it. If that doesn't work try searching for "missing windows taskbar icons." Possible solutions run the gamut from "easy fix" to "not worth the effort."

Comment: if you want to make a bug report: issues.qgis.org

Comment: Problem persists all the way from ver 3.8 to 3.12. Seems confined to Windows 10

Comment: @Sharad You're right. My QGIS 3.10 on my Start panel and Taskbar all have no icons, just a blank sheet.